# Difficulty bundling pg using Mac Postgres App

Tags: macos, postgresql, rubygems, bundle, pg

I've tried bundling my Rails app on my Mac at work. At home it works fine and I've managed it solve it myself previously but this time no matter what I try nothing appears to be working to resolve it.

The error I receive when running bundle/bundle install is the following:

> Installing pg (0.17.0)
>   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/notrab/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> checking for pg_config... no
>   No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
>    --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
>   checking for libpq-fe.h... no
>   Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>     --with-opt-dir
>     --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.
>     --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/notrab/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
>     --with-pg
>     --without-pg
>     --with-pg-config
>     --without-pg-config
>     --with-pg_config
>     --without-pg_config
>     --with-pg-dir
>     --without-pg-dir
>     --with-pg-include
>     --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>     --with-pg-lib
>     --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/notrab/Sites/Integrity/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
>
> Results logged to /Users/notrab/Sites/Integrity/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.

I've obviously tried running

> gem install pg -v '0.17.0' and it says it was successful but bundling again shows the same error.

I have also tried running

> gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config

Which is outlined in the documentation http://postgresapp.com/documentation but the same error occurs when I try to bundle.

I'm going round in circles and don't know how to resolve it.

My Gemfile looks like:

```
group :development, :test do
    gem "better_errors"
    gem 'meta_request'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

Many thanks,

Jamie

Comment: try this .. xcode-select --install

Comment: Sadly that's giving me an error from the Software Update Server.

Comment: make sure ur Internet connection is working fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried adding `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: The issue appears to be with running xcode-select --install not working on my Mac.

Comment: You can verify that the Postgres command line tools are working (and thus that this export command worked properly) by running `psql` and verifying that the psql environment loads. (Then type `\q` to exit.)

Comment: For newer versions of Postgres.app, you probably want `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH`

Comment: For any version of the Postgres.app, this path is better since it's future proof: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`